# Unable to click on Sign-in button

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, xpath, automated-tests

```
<div class="form-group dl-padding-10">

                        <select class="form-control form-control-solid" name="SelectedRoleID" id="SelectedRoleID" onchange="removeBorderColor()" required="">
                              
                        </select>
                        <div class="dl-align-left" id="show_text" style="color:red">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="circle1-mask form-group" id="FingerprintContent" style="height:140px;z-index:2; background-image: none;">
                        <img src="Assets/img/fingerprint4.gif" id="fingerprint-img" data-status="active" style="height:140px; width:100px;" onclick="DeviceScript.scanFingerPrint(event)">
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group dl-padding-10">
                            <button type="submit" id="register-btn" class="btn btn-block dl-button-primary dl-no-margin">Sign In (For Testing Purpose Only)</button>
                        </div>


                </div>
            </div>
</form>    </div>
</div>





<button type="submit" id="register-btn" class="btn btn-block dl-button-primary dl-no-margin">Sign In (For Testing Purpose Only)</button>
```

U can find the HTML code with most information above.

HTML for the button is present in the last line of the above code.

My coding:[code][2]

Error which i get :

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" id="register-btn" class="btn btn-block dl-button-primary dl-no-margin">...</button> is not clickable at point (758, 646). Other element would receive the click: <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">...</div>
```

Kindly help me out on this.

Comment: Hello, this mean button is wrapped in something, normaly div/span etc.. and that element should accept the click, can you paste more html code

Comment: Hi @Infern0 i have attached the image of the HTML code..could u please check the same and guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on registered button Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `ElementToBeClickable`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
 wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("register-btn"))).Click();
```

---

If you still have the same issue then you need to induce `Javascript` Executor to click.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.Id("register-btn")));
```

Comment: Thank u..but i think the problem with me is that i am unable to locate the element of sign-in button..could u pls find the attached image of the full html code and give the exact xpath to locate the sign-in button

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" id="register-btn" class="btn btn-block dl-button-primary dl-no-margin">...</button> is not clickable at point (758, 646). Other element would receive the click: <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">...</div>

Comment: @BalajiMohan : Have you tried the `Javascripts` executor option?

Comment: Hi @KunduK..javascriptexecutor worked for me...thanks a lot